# Error in HttpConnection

Tags: android, httpconnection

I create a code to access webservices but i got a problem when i run the code:

```
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectSocketImpl(Native Method)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:114)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:535)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1054)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:145)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:67)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:821)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:807)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1272)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at com.temp.temp.onCreate(temp.java:85)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-11 17:41:26.821: ERROR/error https(624):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your Java code also and also use `Threads` or `AsyncTask` for network related operations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are connected to Internet and have given these permission in AndroidManfest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I don't think it should be a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code?
And it seems that you have timeout problem with you connection.
Have you already tried to:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 0);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 0);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```